# Need help with repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" OnItemCommand="myRepeater_ItemCommand" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_OnItemDataBound">
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <table width="99%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr class="lgrey">
                <td>Default</td>
             </tr>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" Text="Make Default" CommandName="SetDefault" runat="server" Visible="True" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Yes" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
             </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I want is that when user clicks on any of 
the "lnk1" link button in the list that repeater renders, 
the link should be replaced with the label "label1"..
i.e. when the user clicks on "Make Default" link, it should be replaced with "Yes" label

Calling this method `obj.SetDefaultAddress();` is setting the default address in the DB alright..
problem is with the display of the label1 and lnk1 when the repeater renders...

what is happening is that BOTH "Make Default" LinkButton and the "YES" label are getting displayed 
under the "Default" column of the table inside my repeater.

I want some code that will check the "IsDefault" value in my DB and display "Make Default " link button

and "YES" label accordingly... i.e. if IsDefault's value in the DB is TRUE then "YES" should be displayed in the repeater
otherwise "Make Default"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your piece of code in code behind under ItemCommand is executing?
I only changed the CommandName from SetDefault to SetDefaultAddress in aspx file to match with the one in code behind, it worked.

Comment: I have corrected that...I typed that by mistake..Command names DO match..Its setting the address to default in DB!

Comment: In your edited code, your are using obj.IsDefault, did you tried to check its value in debug mode?

Comment: Debugger shows IsDefault's value as false only apparently that's why "Make Default" link displays inside the repeater. The answerer below says probelm is with Selected Index. How do I fix that ? Plz help..thnx

Comment: Yes I agree with Kendrick, whenever you refresh the page selectedItem will be set to -1. If you tell me somethign about your datasource then may be I can help, like what are the columns it returns.

Comment: Data source is coming from a stored proceedure that simply selects all the columns from UserAddress table that is Address ID,Address1, Address2, City, State, Phone, IsDefault

Comment: hmm, so if you are sure that when you click on default button it correctly updates the database then replace your edited [2] code with 
myR...._DataBound(.....)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            bool bVisible = Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "IsDefault"));
            if (bVisible)
            {
                ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnk1")).Visible = false;
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("label1")).Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @Waqas ::It worked!! YAY :D I just had to add an else block too..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Where to start...

I think what's causing your problem is that the `SelectedItem` and the `DefaultAddress` are not mapped to each other, so when you click the button you're getting the selected index set and the `OnItemDatabound` event is showing/hiding what you want, but when the grid is initialized from the database, the `SelectedItem` is not being set.

I don't know what your datasource is, and there's obviously more code to this than what you've posted, but if you can look at the `e.Item.DataItem` in the `myRepeater_ItemDataBound` handler, you can set the current item as selected when the address is the default (`e.Item.ItemType... or use your "selectedIndex" counter`)

Comment: Data source is coming from a stored proceedure that simply selects all the columns from UserAddress table

Comment: what do I need to change in my code ? I if I dont use that selected index then label doesnt change to "YES" I am lost :/

Answer (score 0):

I will probably do it from markup itself - this is assuming that you have "IsDefault" column/property of bit/boolean type in your data-source indicating the address is default. So use following markup:

```
...
<tr>
   <td>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" Text="Make Default" CommandName="SetDefault" runat="server" Visible='<%# !Eval("IsDefault") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
       <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Yes" runat="server" Visible='<%# !Eval("IsDefault") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

You need to control visibility based on property in your data source (either using markup or ItemDataBound event). Also when SetDefault link is clicked, you must either re-bind the repeater new state or toggle visibility explicitly (as your current code is doing).

EDIT:
If data binding expression are not working then you have to do it in ItemDataBound event. I see that you have already tried that but there is one mistake - `bllUsers obj=new bllUsers();` will always have IsDefault as false - you need to use data item. For example,

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
           bllUsers obj = e.Item.DataItem as bllUsers;
           ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("ldefault")).Visible = obj.isDefault; 
           ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnMakeDefault")).Visible = ! obj.isDefault; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing it exactly like that in the markup! didnt work :( ur saying I need to re-bind the repeater new state...how do I do that and where ? like call the method thats binding repeater ? where do i call it ?

Comment: I am binding repeater in Item Command event like this already :- myRepeater.DataSource = GetAddress();
        myRepeater.DataBind();

Comment: @Serenity, what happens when you use Visible='<%# !Eval("IsDefault") %>' in markup? What is the html generated like - is it generates Visible="True/False" or data binding expression does not get resolved properly?

Comment: the expression does get resolved.. It evaluates to False that's why "Make Default" link button appears

Comment: @Serenity, I hope that you had removed ItemDataBound event when you tried markup because ItemDataBound will override values from markup. But regardless, see my edit in answer for doing the same via ItemDataBound event.