# Replacing Link Button and label with check boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263489/need-help-with-repeater) is my repeater in GUI and code behind ..I need to replace the 'Make Default' linkbutton with a Check Box now. What I want to do is that When user Checks the checbox, the Default value is set to TRUE in DB , Also when a check box is Checked, it will be grayed out..

NOW :( I was just trying to implement this but there's no CommandName attribute for checkbox and not even CommandArgument attribute!!

How do I change my code now ? :(

All I wanna do is replace that Link Button with Checkbox. Somebody please help me out with this..How do i pass arguments to this check box ..I need the command arguments for my "SetDefault" method that sets the address to TRUE if Default is selected

**[EDIT]**

I am not getting it..in my Link Button now I am passing 2 command arguments like this `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") + "," + Eval("IsB") %>'` Now how do i pass these two Comand arguments that I need for my SetDEfault method in checkebox!? ok i got it that we use OnCheckChanged event when its check box and ItemCommand event is used when its link button...I am just not getting how will I pass these two command arguments in my checkbox

[EDIT]
**Do I need to pass these two command arguments via text attribute ?**

```
<asp:CheckBox Text='<%# Eval("UserID") + "," + Eval("IsB") %>' runat="Server"/>
```

Comment: Its not difficult to change the logic from commandName to checkbox specific. What exactly is cauing issue for you?

Comment: I don't see no attribute named CommandArgument in intellisense for checkbox! also dont see Command NAme

Comment: Yh there is no CommandArgument but you have Checked property which is used to determine whether the checkbox was checked or not. You can use this in replacement of CommandName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

followed example here on this page..it worked
http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/279/checkbox-repeater-event-handling-argument

Answer (score 0):

You can just set check box AutoPostBack property to true and use OnCheckedChanged event to use update db.

For example.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked='<%#Eval("Flag")%>' Text='<%#Eval("ItemID")%>'
                            CssClass="HiddenText" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: What does this AutoPostBack="true" do ?

Comment: It will send request to server if control AutoPostBack = "true"

Comment: :How are u passing command argument in that Text attribute..I am not getting it..Is this correct if I need to pass 2 args ? Text='<%# Eval("UserID") + "," + Eval("IsB") %>'

Comment: I mean I dont wanna DISPLAY True/False beside my checkbox. I just want to show it as Checked or unchecked based on its value in DB

Answer (score 0):

Since CheckBox doesnt have CommandName and CommandArgument properties, you could create your own Extended checkbox by extending it from CheckBox class. If you don't know how to do this then here you can find one [Command Capable Checkbox](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2006/10/13/Command_2D00_capable-CheckBox-with-GridView.aspx)

Comment: damn is there no easy way to do this ? Creating a custom control is scary for a newbie like me :(

Comment: I found this..Could u plz tell me how is this guy able to set CommandArgument attribute in Chaeckbox!? http://www.justskins.com/forums/capture-checkbox-click-event-33259.html