# Pass 2 arguments to check box

Tags: c#, asp.net

In [this](http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/279/checkbox-repeater-event-handling-argument) example they are passing only 1 argument. Wat if I wanna pass two ?

When I was using Link Button I was using the two Command arguments like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263489/need-help-with-repeater)

Plz check the ItemCommand event in the code above

Now I am clueless how pass 2 args to CheckBox in the repeater! HElp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

followed below example only..its working

http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/279/checkbox-repeater-event-handling-argument

Answer (score 0):

concatinate the arguments by a separator then split on it when you want to read them. Something like this:

```
chk.CommandArgument = obj1.ID + "," + obj2.ID;


string arguments = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(",");
int id1 = arguments[0];
int id2 = arguments[1];
```

Comment: Thats what I have done in my code when it was a link button! The problem is now I need to use a checkbox in a repeater and thats doesn't support CommandArgument attribute! what now?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the same method as Microgen suggested but use the ToolTip attribute.